# Doctrine error for string foreign key alter

Tags: mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Here is the error I am getting when updating the schema in symfony 3.4.
It give no error when I change the referencedColumnName in second class to id of first class. But when I change it to "costmodelinternal_name" a variable in the first class it give me following error.

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 121:

  An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE cost_model_internal ADD CONSTRAINT FK_F59CC1232B401EC6 FOREIGN K
  EY (costmodelinternal_name) REFERENCES bonus_calculation_1 (costmodelinternal_name)':

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint


In PDOConnection.php line 106:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint


In PDOConnection.php line 104:

  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint


doctrine:schema:update [--complete] [--dump-sql] [-f|--force] [--em [EM]] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command>
```

Here is classes related fields (one-to-many) relation

```
class BonusCalculation1
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="CostModelInternal", mappedBy="bonus_calculation1")
     */
    private $cost_model_internals;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->cost_model_internals = new ArrayCollection();
    }
}

class CostModelInternal
{
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="BonusCalculation1", inversedBy="cost_model_internals")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="costmodelinternal_name", referencedColumnName="costmodelinternal_name")
     */
    private $bonus_calculation1;
}
```

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: Can you add the definition of "costmodelinternal_name" property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I am trying to build a relation using no primary key property. Which is not allowed in doctrine